# how to execute replace() in python using subprocess.run()

Tags: python, replace, subprocess

how to execute the replace function in python using the subprocess in python

```
oldstring="i want to move it"
newstring="i want to touch it"
subprocess.run(["replace","move","touch"])
```

tried this but doesn't work
the question says to use the subprocess module

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do? Why do you think subprocess is the right tool to use?

Comment: i am told to use subprocess in the question that is why i am using it

Comment: So "replace" is an external program? What does it do?

Comment: it replaces the old sub string with the new sub string in a sentence

Comment: you don't need subprocess for that... `oldstring.replace("move", "touch")`

Comment: but the question says to use the subprocess.run()

Comment: I think we need to see the full question to understand what you are being asked to do - as explained it makes no sense.